# PS button on DualSense controller forces opening launchpad on Ventura

Tags: games, launchpad, ventura, peripheral

Whenever I press the PS button on my DualSense controller, it opens up the LaunchPad app, which means I can't use it to open up things like Steam settings.  Apparently, on previous versions, there were ways around this, but Ventura removes these.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an option for this on Monterey (and before), but this has vanished with Ventura.

The only option I see here is to do it with Terminal. You can run the following command to stop the PS button (logo) from opening Launchpad :

```
defaults write com.apple.GameController bluetoothPrefsMenuLongPressAction -integer 0
```

You might need to reboot for the changes to apply.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There was no need to reboot on macOS Ventura 13.4; the changes took effect immediately. The PS button no longer invokes LaunchPad, but still works as expected in apps like Sony's PS Remote Play, eliminating the conflict between the app and system behavior.

Comment: @JohnWhitley Yes, you are right on this point, I’ve edited the answer to state that you might need to reboot. Normally running commands with `defaults write` do need a reboot but only of the specific app they are affecting.